# Unable to build android cpp: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::GameServices::"

Tags: android, c++, google-play-services

I'm setup the google game service, following the google guideline at https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid.

Here my CMake:

```
add_library(native_app_glue STATIC ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)
add_library(cpufeatures STATIC ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c)
add_library(gpg_sdk STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(gpg_sdk PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GPG_SDK_PATH}/lib/c++/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgpg.a)
    
target_include_directories(${APP_NAME}
        PRIVATE Classes
        ${GPG_SDK_PATH}/include
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/cpufeatures
)

add_subdirectory(firebase_cpp_sdk)
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} cocos2d native_app_glue cpufeatures)
```

When I run the build there have an error:

```
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2338: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::GameServices::~GameServices()'
```

my gradle build

```
            cmake {
                targets 'MyGame'
                arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=",
                          "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static",
                          "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                          "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE",
                          "-DPLAYCORE_LOCATION=$playcoreDir"
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
```

Note: I used the NDK r21,

I try to use the cppFlags "-std=c++11 " or -std=c++17 or "-stdlib=libc++" but not success.

Can any one faced this issue?
I following the https://forum.defold.com/t/problem-with-google-play-game-services-def-2896/11288/2, but seem not success?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by add target_link_libraries( .... gpg_sdk);